# JavaScript resize event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have some code like:

```
function Cname(id, name)
{
    ...
}

Cname.prototype.dosomething = function()
{
    ...
    //1. $(window).resize(this.handle_resize);
    //2. var self = this;
    //   $(window).resize(function(e, self){
    //       self.handle_resize(e);
    //   });
    ...
}

Cname.prototype.handle_resize= function(e)
{
}
```

I tried two ways to register `handle_resize` for window resize event as shown above, but both do not work. I understand how it works in case of global functions.

How can I make it work when a function is member of a Class?

Comment: the second way in not correct - it should be `$(window).resize(function(e) { self.handle_resize(e); });`. Put some alerts to debug (or use debugger from FireBug/Chrome/IE8) - e.g. `alert(this.handle_resize)` in dosomething should alert 'object'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var self = this;
$(window).resize(function(e){
    self.handle_resize(e);
    });
```